# How to efficiently initialize objects of large class

Tags: c++, class

Say I have a class which contains several (+100) data members. For this question we use an example with just 6 members for clarity:

```
class A
{
  public:
    int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6;

    A(int a,
      int b,
      int c,
      int d,
      int e,
      int f)
        : v1(a),
          v2(b),
          v3(c),
          v4(d),
          v5(e),
          v6(f){};
};
```

Now, say I want to create **a single** object of this class. Due to the large number of members, I'd like to initialize the object in a separate function in order not to clutter up the `main`. To my knowledge I can do this in two ways:

**Method 1:**

```
A test()
{
    return temp_a(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}

int main()
{
    A a = test();
}
```

**Method 2:** (pass by reference)

```
void test(vector<A>& a)
{
    A temp_a(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    a.push_back(temp_a);
}

int main()
{
    vector<A> a;
    test(a);
}
```

**Question** Which of these methods are best in terms of **efficiency** and **professionalism** when initializing objects of large classes? I personally prefer **method 2** as I alter the vector directly. The downside is that I have to refer to `a[0]` everytime I want to access the members of the object.

Comment: *"Say I have a class which contains several (+100) data members"*... that immediately sounds like a design problem. Your classes probably do way too much work and are over complicated.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, corrected it. @CoryKramer The number `100` was somewhat arbitrary, let's say 20, 30 or 40 instead.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way than my suggestion. Is it feasible to break up the member variables into their own related groups inside container classes? Alternatively use a factory pattern where the factory gathers the member values and initializes them for you. Perhaps with greater context on how you intend to use your class there would be better suggestions.

Comment: First method seems better, and you can use `std::unique_ptr` to allow cheaper move semantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 2 will be both less efficient and less idiomatic C++.

The copies and/or moves caused by method 1 will almost certainly be elided by your compiler.  Return Value Optimization (RVO) will cause the `A` object to be constructed in its final place (`a`) from within `test()`, as though you had written *something like* this:

```
A * test(void *a)
{
    return new (a) A(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}

int main()
{
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A), alignof(A)>::type a_mem;

    A &a = *test(a_mem);

    // The rest of your code.

    // Technically this is not exception-safe, but for the purposes of
    // illustration, assume that the following line will be called even if
    // an exception is thrown between the line initializing the "a" reference
    // and this line.
    a.~A();
}
```

The point is, if you think this is going to be a performance bottleneck then you should do benchmarks to verify this.  The compiler is a lot smarter than us, and it is very good at optimizing away a lot of things.

It is very likely that any bottlenecks are going to be elsewhere in your code.

It's more important to make your code correct and obvious in its meaning to future maintainers than it is to eek out a tiny bit more performance (unless you are on a critical path).  Further, compilers have a much easier time optimizing simple and straightforward code than they do complicated workarounds.  (For example, in the method 2 the compiler can't easily optimize away the heap allocation caused by `std::vector` so you're actually *de-optimizing* by adding an extra level of indirection that the compiler can't see through.)